# $\epsilon, \epsilon/2 $ Proof

Tags: real-analysis

How is it proved that $$ \left[ |X_n - X|+|Y_n-Y| \geq \epsilon \right] \subset \{ \left[ |X_n -X|\geq \epsilon/2 \right] + \left[ |Y_n-Y| \geq \epsilon/2 \right] \} $$

Thank you.

Comment: I am baffled as to what this notation actually means :)

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (And perhaps also [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, if you add two positive numbers and get at least $1$, at least one of them must be greater than $\frac 12$.  To be more formal, it is probably easier to prove the contrapositive:  assume $|X_n-X| \lt \epsilon/2$ and $|Y_n-Y| \lt \epsilon/2$.  Then you can bound the left side of the sum by $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thanks but how does that prove that one is a subset of the other? That's what I am having trouble understanding.

Comment: I am taking the complement of the right side and showing that it is a subset of the complement of the left.  So I take a point in the right side complement and show that it is in the left side complement.